# Django multiple .dates() for query search

Tags: django, model

I have a module that looks something like

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    #
    # date for the post
    date = models.DateField()
```

`date` stores the date for the post will show. What I want to get is a listing of all months and years for all posts by a user. So it will look something like

```
7/2015
8/2015
10/2015
```

I've tried this

```
Entry.objects.filter(user=self.user) \
            .order_by('-date') \
            .dates('date', 'year') \
            .distinct()
```

That gives me the unique years.. Is there anyway to do this in a query where I dont have to select the unique months and iterate over them to create an object.

My raw sql looked like

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS y, MONTH(date) AS m FROM entries WHERE userid ='". $this->id ."' ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think you just need to use `month` as the second parameter to the [QuerySet.dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#dates) function. E.g.,

`self.user.entry_set.order_by('-date').dates('date', 'month')`

would return a list of distinct year/month values for all of `self.user`'s `Entry`.

You can then format each datetime object as you see fit.